# Django: How to display all the products in a particular category

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, python-3.2

In my admin page I have 2 apps. One for the Category and the other is for the Products.

In the category I have PS3 and PS4, and in the products..well.. I have the products.

What I want to do is display all of the products for the category. How would I do this? On my html pages, I have a menu bar: Home, PS3 and PS4. When someone clicks on the PS3 or PS4 tab, I want it to display the products for each tab, instead of creating a seperate category page and details page.

In my database I have the following fields for Category: name. In the Products I have the following fields: title, description, image, price, stock.

I have all the pages working, but I just need to display the products. I hope I am clear. I cannot do this. I will show my code..

MODELS.PY..

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
            ordering = ["name"] 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Products(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_images", blank=True)


     class Meta:
            ordering = ["title", "description", "image", "price", "stock"]

    def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

IN MY VIEWS.PY...

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse
from category.models import *

def home(request):
      return render_to_response("category/index.html",locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def ps3(request):
     return render_to_response("category/ps3.html",locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def ps4(request):
return render_to_response("category/ps4.html",locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

IN MY URLS.PY..

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', 'category.views.home', name='home'),
    url('^ps3/', 'category.views.ps3', name ='ps3'),
    url('^ps4/', 'category.views.ps4', name ='ps4'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

)
```

Comment: where do you want to show ? in the admin or in the regular app ?

Answer (score 0):

The `context_instance` argument is the important part here, as you can see, it's a `RequestContext` class, this class takes a `request` as its first argument, and you can pass any data you want as a dictionary in the second argument:

```
c = RequestContext(request, {
    'foo': 'bar',
})
```

You need to make use of this, to pass the data you want to use in your templates.
And please, learn to Don’t repeat yourself (DRY), and apply that in your URLs/Views.

Comment: I dont think this necessarily answers the OP's question.

Comment: Why doesn't it? And how could you use `category` in the template if it's not in the context so begin with?